# e.target not recognising element

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a size select function with each size pulling through on a separate tile as below: [size tiles][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSzDy.png

The issue I am having is that if the tiles have more than one of the clock images my code doesn't recognise the clock image on the second tile.

My code looks like this:

```
          const dropDown = (): string =>
            `<div class = "selectWrapper">
       <div class="numberWrapper">${options
         .map(
           (option) =>
             `${
               option.stockStatus === 'OUT_OF_STOCK'
                 ? `<button class="notAvailable" ><p class = "size">${option.value}</p></button>`
                 : option.stockStatus === 'LOW_STOCK'
                 ? `<button class="selectSize" ><svg class = "low" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                 <path d="M12 22C17.5228 22 22 17.5228 22 12C22 6.47715 17.5228 2 12 2C6.47715 2 2 6.47715 2 12C2 17.5228 6.47715 22 12 22Z" stroke="#FFBF00" stroke-width="1.2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                 <path d="M12 5.17999V12L15.04 15.04" stroke="#FFBF00" stroke-width="1.2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                 </svg><p class = "size">${option.value}</p></button>`
                 : `<button class="selectSize" ><p class = "size">${option.value}</p></button>`
             }`
         )
         .join('')}
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>`

          const selected = () => document.querySelector('.selectWrapper')

          const getOption = (): void => {
            selected()!.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
              const target = e.target as HTMLElement
              console.log(target)
              const selectedLength = (e.target as HTMLElement).textContent
                ?.length
              const selectedVal = (e.target as HTMLElement).textContent
              // const valSelectedTeens = selectedVal?.substring(
              //   selectedVal.length - selectedLength!
              // )
              const valSelected = selectedVal?.substring(
                selectedVal.length - selectedLength!
              )

              for (let i = 0; i < sizeDropDownVal()!.length; i++) {
                const originalValue = sizeDropDownVal()![i] as HTMLOptionElement

                if (target.contains(document.querySelector('.low'))) {
                  const childValLength = target.children[1].textContent?.length
                  const childValSelected = selectedVal?.substring(
                    selectedVal.length - childValLength!
                  )
                  console.log('yes')
                  if (
                    originalValue.innerText.includes(childValSelected as string)
                  ) {
                    originalValue.selected = true
                    sizeDropDownVal()!.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log('no')
                  if (originalValue.innerText.includes(valSelected as string)) {
                    originalValue.selected = true
                    sizeDropDownVal()!.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
                  }
                }
              }
            })
          }

          getOption()
        })
```

For some reason if I click on the second tile with the clock image my console logs 'no' which would imply that the clock does not exist on that tile when in fact it does. I hope this makes sense and someone will be able to help!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run all the code, but I think this part of your if statement is the culprit:

`target.contains(document.querySelector('.low'))`

`document.querySelector()` is going to get the first instance of that selector within the **whole** document, not the `target` element. In this case, the first instance of that selector is the first button with it in, causing the second button to fail.

Try `target.querySelector('.low')` instead?

Comment: thank you so much! Wasn't aware that document.querySelector only recognises the first instance of the whole document. This has worked a treat!